# How to show grid lines in Collecionview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, collectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am doing Swift application with custom collectionview. I would like to show columns rows in that and I have achieved it.
But, I would like to show grid lines inside the cells.

Below is my code:

**Viewcontroller class**

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var theData = [[String]]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        theData = [
            ["1", "Name", "TV", "LCD", "LED", ""],
            ["2", "Market", "No", "Charge", "Discount", ""],
            ["3", "value", "2.00", "05.00", "49.30", "200", ""],
            ["4", "Coupons", "1", "1","1","1","Total Price: "]]
        
        let layout = CustomLayout()
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    }
    
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData[section].count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell?.myLabel.text = theData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}
```

**Custom collectionviewflowlayout class**

```
import UIKit

class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    let  itemWidth = 200
    let itemHeight = 200

   func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
       
        let xSize = (collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))! * (itemWidth + 2) // the 2 is for spacing between cells.
        let ySize = collectionView!.numberOfSections * (itemHeight + 2)
        return CGSize(width: xSize, height: ySize)
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at path: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        
        var attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? = nil
        if let path = path {
            attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: path)
            var xValue: Int
            attributes?.size = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
            xValue = itemWidth / 2 + (path.row ) * (itemWidth + 2)
            let yValue = itemHeight + (path.section ) * (itemHeight + 2)
            attributes?.center =  CGPoint(x:CGFloat(xValue), y:CGFloat(yValue))
        }
        return attributes
   }
    
    func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [AnyHashable]? {
        
        let minRow = Int((rect.origin.x > 0) ? Int(rect.origin.x) / (itemWidth + 2) : 0) // need to check because bounce gives negative values  for x.

        let maxRow = Int(Int(rect.size.width) / (itemWidth + 2) + minRow)
        var attributes: [AnyHashable] = []
        for i in 0..<(self.collectionView?.numberOfSections)! {
            for j in (minRow..<maxRow) {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: j, section: i)
                attributes.append(layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath))
            }
        }
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Also I would like change background color only for header titles (1,2,3,4).

Any suggestions?

[image]

I would like to show like below screenshot gridlines
[image]

Comment: Did you try with applying collection cell layer border width and color ?

Comment: You can look at supplementary views for your header and probably the grid lines can be a decoration view if you want to customize your layout. Otherwise, grid lines can be part of your custom cell itself as borders.

Comment: @Jenish Yes, I have tried, but it is coming like inner label border, not for entire cell.

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative Then its seems like your collection cell width is not equally divided as per screen size. You need to give cell width dynamically (count based screen width/no of cell you want). Check your cell by giving background color then you can get better idea.

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative - this is a bit confusing... it looks like you want 4 "columns" that will (with enough rows) scroll vertically, but you're configuring a horizontal flow layout? Also, it's not clear what you want to do with your 4th data set, which has a different number of elements?

Comment: @DonMag There are 5 to 6 rows, i just posted here sample screenshot. So it needed horizontal scroll

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative - OK... when posting here, it's a good idea to provide complete information about what you're trying to do. Probably the most straight-forward way to get "grid lines" is to use **1-point** for `.minimumInteritemSpacing` and `.minimumLineSpacing` and give your collection view a black background color.

Comment: @DonMag I have tried with         layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .black
but its not showing gridlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to have a "fixed grid" - that is, x-columns by y-rows - you can calculate your cell layout in `prepare()`, save the `cellAttributes` in an array, and then use that array for `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)`:

```
class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    private var computedContentSize: CGSize = .zero
    private var cellAttributes = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    let itemWidth = 100
    let itemHeight = 60

    let gridLineWidth = 1
    
    override func prepare() {
        
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            fatalError("not a collection view?")
        }
        
        // Clear out previous results
        computedContentSize = .zero
        cellAttributes = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        
        let numItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        let numSections = collectionView.numberOfSections

        let widthPlusGridLineWidth = itemWidth + gridLineWidth
        let heightPlusGridLineWidth = itemHeight + gridLineWidth
        
        for section in 0 ..< numSections {
            for item in 0 ..< numItems {
                let itemFrame = CGRect(x: item * widthPlusGridLineWidth + gridLineWidth,
                                       y: section * heightPlusGridLineWidth + gridLineWidth,
                                       width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
                
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = itemFrame
                
                cellAttributes[indexPath] = attributes
            }
        }
        
        computedContentSize = CGSize(width: numItems * widthPlusGridLineWidth + gridLineWidth, height: numSections * heightPlusGridLineWidth + gridLineWidth) // Store computed content size
    }
    
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return computedContentSize
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var attributeList = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        
        for (_, attributes) in cellAttributes {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                attributeList.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        
        return attributeList
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellAttributes[indexPath]
    }
    
}
```

Your controller class then becomes:

```
class OutlinedGridViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    private let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
    
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var theData = [[String]]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // set view background to systemYellow so we can see the
        //  collection view frame
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        theData = [
            ["1", "Name", "TV", "LCD", "LED", "", ""],
            ["2", "Market", "No", "Charge", "Discount", "", ""],
            ["3", "value", "2.00", "05.00", "49.30", "200", ""],
            ["4", "Coupons", "1", "1","1","1","Total Price: "]]
        
        let layout = CustomLayout()
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .black
    }

    
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return theData[0].count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        
        let d = theData[indexPath.item]
        cell.myLabel.text = d[indexPath.section]

        // set background color for top row, else use white
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = indexPath.section == 0 ? .yellow : .white

        return cell
    }

}
```

and, using this custom cell (a single, centered label):

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var myLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        myLabel.textColor = .black
        myLabel.textAlignment = .center
        myLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
        
        let g = contentView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            myLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            myLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            myLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            myLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),

        ])
    }
    
}
```

We get this (I made the collection view slightly smaller than needed, so we can see the horizontal and vertical scrolling):

[image]

[image]

You didn't explain what you want to do with the "Total Price" row... but if your intent is to have fewer columns on the last row, modifying this code will be a good exercise for you :)

Comment: Very nice. Had a quick question, when creating custom layouts - I notice some places they call `super.prepare()` and some places this is left out inside the prepare functions. Is there any best practice / rule of thumb for this ?

Comment: From Apple's docs: *The default implementation of this method does nothing.* ... so you don't need to call `super`. In general, the docs will say "you **must** call super" if it's needed. Of course, if you have subclassed a layout subclass, *that* class may be using `prepare()`, then you would want to call `super.prepare()` in *your* class.

Comment: Thanks DonMag, cleared this up for me .. much appreciated !

Comment: @DonMag thanks so much for your valuable suggestions and help. Is it possible to make label height and width dynamically set?

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative - umm... sure? Not exactly clear what you're asking.

Comment: @DonMag is it possible to make cell height based on text like dynamic height?

Comment: @AnilkumariOS-ReactNative - it's pretty much possible to do *anything*... but you're asking a very vague question. Do you want multi-line labels in your cells? Are you asking about setting the "row height" based on font size? Do you need different width "columns"? Different fonts in different cells? Use that example code ***as a starting point*** and try to implement the "dynamic" aspects that you have in mind.